# Probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

Let’s say I have a 10 sided box, there is an equal probability that any side of the box will be facing upwards. Each side of the box is of a different colour. I roll 5 of these boxes an unknown number of times. What is the mean value of obtaining blue facing upwards? I know this question is linked to expectation value but I am unsure what probability distribution to use. Can anyone help me setting up the equation? Thanks!

Comment: and blue, or all blue?

Comment: Blue could be facing upwards any number of times.

Comment: Welcome. // There are different ways to perceive the situation, assuming all other 9 colors are different, i.e. it's a drawing-black-white problem. // Then "blue" has probability p=1/10=0.1 on a single dice. // You could check out binomial, tree diagrams and similar. You could also create random numbers, e.g. via R, and check the (experimental) outcome for 1, 2, ... 5, ... N dices thrown 1, 10, 100, 1.000 times.

Comment: Welcome Voldewort. I think your question might be better suited to the [Cross Validated statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)  where hundreds of dice statistics questions have been asked and answered.  The question would be more relevant here on the Physics site if it was about dice physics.

Comment: To be clear, you have not explicitly stated that each of your "boxes" actually has a blue side.  The answer could be zero in the case that all sides are some color different than blue.  That being said, this is a textbook example of binomial distribution and/or linearity of expectation.  Each roll of the box lands on blue (*presumably*) with probability $0.1$.  The mean number of blues seen in $n$ rolls would be $0.1\cdot n$, following from standard results.

Comment: If you are interested in not counting the number of blue results within the five roles, but rather are interested in the probability of at least one blue showing within the five rolls... that too is a quintessential example of binomial distribution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct probability distribution is "uniform", since each color has an equal probability. Uniform random number generators usually produce floating point output from 0 to 1. Here you want the target space to be $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$.

On a computer you just multiply your uniform random number generator by 10 and cast to an integer.

Since you're interested in 1 color, assign it to 0. Generate 5 results. Take the logical not of the output and check for any true results in the list.

That converts the output to a boolean, where True means Blue.

Repeat 100,000 times and sum the results, here in python2:

[image]

Now compare to theory.

The probability of a blue side on one die is

$$ P_B=\frac 1 {10}$$

so the probably of not blue is

$$P_{\bar B}=1-P_B=1-\frac 1 {10}=\frac 9 {10}$$

The probability of all 5 being not blue is

$$P^{(5)}_{\bar B}= P_{\bar B}^5 = (\frac 9 {10})^5 = \frac{59049}{100000}$$

Thus, the probability of at least 1 blue is:

$$P^{(5)}_{ B}=1-P^{(5)}_{\bar B} = \frac{40951}{100000}$$

which is pretty close to the 40,982 from the computer.

Note that the test of 5 die is a Bernoulli process with probability of success $p=0.4095$.

Testing that 100,000 times is a Binomial distribution with number of trials $n=100,000$.

The variance of that is:

$$\sigma^2 = np(1-p)$$

so that the standard deviation is:

$$ \sigma \approx 156$$

so the computer code checks out.

Comment: When the theoretical answer is so trivial and standard, it is incredibly unnecessary to even mention computer simulation.  The answer could have been given in one or two sentences... "*The distribution is a common one known as a binomial distribution which is well known to have mean $np$*" or "*Linearity of expectation applies meaning we just add the probability to itself $n$ times here to get $np$.*"  Nothing more beyond perhaps a link to a wiki article should be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone! I understand the binomial distribution and expectation value a lot clearer now.

Comment: @Voldewort Well, this was migrated from PHYSICS stackexchange, where 1 LoC doesn't warrant such protestations.